# HTML RenderAction - redirection in ActionResult method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, actionresult

Inside the controller of a `RenderAction` request

```
@{Html.RenderAction("abc", "Controller"); }
```

I am trying to redirect to a new controller if something so goes wrong, however this redirect gets ingored so the site just crashes. So how do I redirect as the code that I have done below doesn't work?

Am wondering if its to do with the `ChildActionOnly` attribute?

Thanks

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult abc()
{
   if(....) 
   {
      // if all is OK return this view
      return View("view", ViewModel
      {
           ...
           ...
      });
   }
   else
   {   
      // This is the problem..
      return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "controller");
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Child actions cannot perform redirects.

One alternative is to use JavaScript (jQuery used in example below) in your main view to perform a request to the method, which will do something if it fails:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction")'
}).fail(function() {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("SomethingWentWrong")';
}).done(function(data) {
    // display data
});
```

Then simply return a 500 error from `SomeAction`.